# where is documention for rspec's should function applied to various things

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried googling the keywords `ruby` `rails` `rspec` `should` but `should` is too general of a word to find documentation on it. I want to know the various things I can do with should thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-expectations/RSpec/Matchers (rspec 2.8)
http://rspec.rubyforge.org/rspec/1.2.8/classes/Spec/Matchers.html (rspec 1.2.8)

Comment: That's for the first version of RSpec, while actual is 2.8.

Comment: @p0deje good call, thanks. I updated with a link to the latest docs, which admittedly was harder to find than I'd like. https://github.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/tree/master/lib/rspec/matchers is also a good resource.

Answer (score 0):

`#should` and `#should_not` are generally don't need to be that documented. The main thing about them is that they take expectation method as argument. The documentation for latter is at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/docs